# Child processes waiting on each other

Tags: linux, process, fork, waitpid

I created three processes and I want to synchronize their work. Specifically, I want the first process to wait on the second, second on third. Basically execute them in the reverse order they were created in.

Here is what i did so far.

```
for (; i < 3 ; i++){
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] == 0)
           break;
}
if (pids[i] != 0){
    wait(); // Main thread has to wait..    
}
else{               
     if (i == 0){
        waitpid(pids[1], &status, 0);       
        printProcessInfo(0);        
     }
     else if (i == 1){
        waitpid(pids[2], &status, 0);       
        printProcessInfo(1);        
          }
     else if (i == 2){
        printProcessInfo(2);        
     }              
}
```

I am using i to check which child process I am in because I am assuming I get the correct i in the child process, so if i = 0, i am in fact in the fist child. Is this assumption true? In any case I don't get the order I want, in fact the processes get executed in their natural order, bypassing the waitpid calls I placed. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? This is a lot easier if each child creates a child. As you currently have it no child is going to know about its younger siblings, just the older ones. IOW, when the parent creates child1, child1 is its own process. The pid table for that process is not going to be updated to reflect further children. Only the parent's pid table has all the info. Your waitpid() calls are probably failing on ECHILD (that you are not checking for) and that is why it seems they aren't being executed.

Comment: I figured. This was a very confusing school assignment because the professor specifically asked us not to make the first fork the second and so on, so I was confused. I think I will look into some other form of IPC, even tough we are not in that chapter yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are getting more then 3 process.

Consider a simplified version (this is just removed wait... you do the same number of fork):

```
for (i=0; i < 3 ; i++){
    pids[i] = fork();
}
```

Because you do the fork inside a for-loop, without checking the return value. Both parent and child will get its own child.

```
    [###############PARENT###############]
          |           |           |
         i=0         i=1         i=2
          |           |           |
        [ a0 ]      [ b0 ]      [ c0 ]
         / \          |
       i=1 i=2       i=2
       /     \        |
     [a1]   [a2]    [ b1 ]
      |
     i=2
      |
     [a3]
```

You have to break the loop after checking the return value for `fork`.

Comment: Believe it or not my original code did break from the loop. Anyway, I added a break statement in case its the child process, now, my main question, is the code I wrote to supposedly help reverse the order of execution of the child processes correct?

Comment: Yeah, but I figured the problem here is that sometimes the second child waits for nothing, as the second was not created yet (waitpid returns -1). Turns out a process can't wait for its siblings using this technique. Thanks for your answer though, it helped a lot.